# What to advise graphics designer designing layout and images to be suitable for multiple screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-screen, android-screen-support

I've read the Android Developers guidance on Supporting Multiple Screens here...

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

... and I understand from a developer's perspective the easiest way to cater for most screens is to have three sets of drawables and layouts (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi) and to use relative positioning in layout files and to specify heights, widths etc in density independent pixels.

I'm going to have a graphics designer design my screens and the individual buttons, images etc  who'll be designing for high density screens (240dpi) and then scaling the graphics down by 1.5 for medium density screens (160dpi) and by 2 for low density screens (120dpi). Is this the best way to go about? And what, if anything, can I advise him/her about the height and width of the screen to design for?

Comment: don't forget xhdpi (320dpi), as that will become quite prominent soon.

Comment: Are there are any (many?) devices out there already of the xhdpi range?

Comment: only the Galaxy Nexus and HTC Rezound at the moment, but I'm sure there will be a glut soon enough. It seems that Android are trying to phase out ldpi, but for now it's probably best to make resources for all four dpis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [this article](http://realmike.org/blog/2010/12/21/multiple-screen-sizes-with-processing-for-android/) this is one of the best article regarding this.

Google suggests using 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio for ldpi:mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi accordingly, So please scale images according to this ratio.

Yes, You should tell him to create images for large screens -480dp x 640dp

Comment: and when you'll have images for large screen phone, you can scale them accordingly.